# implementar una función para seleccionar aleatoriamente una palabra de un archivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

debo definir  una función que escoja aleatoriamente una palabra que se encuentra en en archivo de texto, hasta ahora abrí el archivo tipo txt y lo convertí en una lista y extraje  la palabra aleatoria, pero no he logrado definir la función que me permita usarlo después.

```
intro = open("intro.txt", "r")
lista_pal = list(pal)
palabra = random.choice(lista_pal)
```

Comment: por favor revisa [ask] y de paso realiza el [tour] la comunidad con gusto te apoyará resolviendo dudas del código que intentes pero no lo hará por ti, dale editar a tu pregunta y añade lo que haz tratado/investigado

Comment: El código que has puesto no está bien. Supongo que `list(pal)` debe ser `list(intro)`.  Suponiendo que estuviera bien, basta que metas el código que has escrito dentro de una función que reciba como parámetro el nombre del fichero (para así poder elegir otro distinto de `intro.txt` y al final de la misma pongas `return palabra`. De este modo desde otra parte del programa puedes poner algo como `elegida = elige_palabra("intro.txt")`